Apache ldap authentication: ldap authentication configuration with conflicting conditions
I'm configuring Apache for LDAP authentication using LDAPURL, LDAPBindDN, and LDAPBindPassword. But there's a conflict between AuthLDAPURL and AuthLDAPBindDN conditions. 
My config looks something like:
AuthLDAPURL ldap://server.domain.com/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)
AuthLDAPBindDN binduser@domain.com
AuthLDAPBindPassword password


What I'm aiming for is to accept either condition, perhaps using an OR operator. I attempted to use Require ldap-filter "|(AuthLDAPURL)(AuthLDAPBindDN)", but it's not working as intended. Is there a way to configure Apache to accept both conditions?

You misunderstand the purpose of AuthLDAPBindDN. It is the DN which Apache should use when logging into LDAP to do the check. It isn’t an authentication constraint at all.
